# Eigenvalues of $A$ vs eigenvalues of $2A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_n$. Then $2A$ has eigenvalues $2\lambda_1, . . . , 2\lambda_n$.

I don't know how to prove it. Is anybody here have an idea? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $v$ is an eigenvector that corresponds to $\lambda$ for $A$

Then $(2A)v = 2(Av) = 2\lambda v$ so $v$ is an eigenvector for $2A$ with eigenvalue $2\lambda$

Comment: what if using any constant say $k \in \mathbb{C}$. $ kA$  has eigenvalues  $kλ_1,...,kλ_n$? does it also holds?

Comment: @ElNumeral Can you answer your question by yourself?

Comment: @ElNumeral just look at my answer and see if i used the fact that $k=2$ in any way.